# wpf mvvm visualstate manager change state before loaded

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visualstatemanager

I want to change state before control loaded. I have to change the state when  loaded event fire  or later but usercontrol hasn't contentRendered event. Is there any solution.

here my code:

**View:**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStateGroup">

            <VisualState x:Name="CameraConnected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0EE603"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="label">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="StaticResource Connected}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="BaseState"></VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    private bool _isConnected = false;
    public const string IsConnectedPropertyName = "IsConnected";

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isConnected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isConnected == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _isConnected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(IsConnectedPropertyName);
        }
    }
    internal void userControl_Loaded()
    {
        IsConnected = true;
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not set your View up - like it should be - bevore its loaded - instead of trying to change it - bevore it is loaded?

Comment: Because it can be change. the property come from another system. so it can be connected or disconnected.

Comment: Then i would try to change it - bevore `InitializeComponent();` gets called.

Comment: But it can happens after InitializeComponent();

Comment: Then wait for the call - bevore you start building up your UI - dont event know if `InitializeComponent();` is the right call here mate.

Comment: user must see is it connected or not. i cant change senario. i just need change state before loading or later

Comment: I dont see a problem in this scenario ...

Comment: Start -> Ask for Connection -> Get Connection -> RaisePropertyChanged -> Change State

Comment: what is ask for connection. how can i do that. EDIT: RaisePropertyChanged  does not work before loaded event